# cl-rassoc-if not work

Tags: association-lists

```
(setq fileset '((arch
                 . ("a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt" "d.txt" "e.txt"))
                (emacs
                 . ("f.txt" "g.txt"))))
(cl-rassoc-if (lambda (el)
                (member "a.txt" (cdr el))) 
  fileset)
```

The result is `nil` which I expected to be `(arch . ("a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt" "d.txt" "e.txt"))`. Why `cl-rassoc-if` does not work?

Comment: Because it finds the 1st item whose **CDR** satisfies your lambda form.  You don't need to call `cdr` again.

Comment: @shynur Please change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `cl-rassoc-if`

> finds the 1st item whose **cdr** satisfies the predicate (the 1st argument) in the list (the 2nd argument).

This function passes ***CDR*** of each item in the list you provided to the predicate you provided, so you don't need to call `cdr` in your predicate (i.e., your lambda expr) again.

In your example, the 1st item in list `fileset` is

```lisp
(arch
 . ("a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt" "d.txt" "e.txt"))
```

and its *CDR* is

```lisp
("a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt" "d.txt" "e.txt")
```

, which is passed to the lambda expression as the argument `el`.

Then `(cdr el)` evaluates to `("b.txt" "c.txt" "d.txt" "e.txt")`.

---

###### Correct Version

```lisp
(setq fileset '((arch
                 . ("a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt" "d.txt" "e.txt"))
                (emacs
                 . ("f.txt" "g.txt"))))
(cl-rassoc-if (lambda (el)
                (member "a.txt" el)) fileset)
```